# Why doesn’t the form not POST in Excel 2016 for Mac?

Tags: macos, post, add-in, office-addins, excel-2016

We are testing an add-in for Excel that has a form that is POSTed to https://httpbin.org/anything. The form will not POST in Excel 2016 version 15.39 (171010) for Mac (High Sierra ver 10.13.1). Here are the HTML form’s essentials:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  //submit form
  $("#testForm").submit();

</script>

</head>
<body>

  <form method="POST" id="testForm" action="https://httpbin.org/anything" accept-charset="UTF-8" target="_blank">

    <div>
      <input type='hidden' name='mergeDataFormat' value='csv'>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="mergeData" id="mergeData" value='Name,Street,"City, State",ZIP Code'>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submitForm" />

  </form>
```

AppDomain was set in the Manifest:

```
<AppDomains>
   <AppDomain>https://httpbin.org/</AppDomain>
   ...
</AppDomains>
```

This is what we see in Charles HTTP monitor ver 4.2:

```
GET /anything HTTP/1.1
Host httpbin.org
Connection keep-alive
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
Upgrade-Insecure-Reque
sts 1
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie _gauges_unique_day=1; _gauges_unique_month=1; _gauges_unique_year=1; _gauges_unique=1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: meinheld/0.6.1
Date: Wed, 15 Nov 2017 18:07:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Powered-By: Flask
X-Processed-Time: 0.00142621994019
Content-Length: 726
Via: 1.1 vegur
Connection: Keep-alive
{
"args": {},
"data": "",
"files": {},
"form": {},
"headers": {
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Connection": "close",
"Cookie": "_gauges_unique_day=1; _gauges_unique_month=1; _gauges_unique_year=1; _gauges_unique=1",
"Host": "httpbin.org",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
},
"json": null,
"method": "GET",
"origin": "<ip-address-here>",
"url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
}
```

After pressing the Send button, the httpbin.org page pops up to show this:

```
{
"args": {},
"data": "",
"files": {},
"form": {},
"headers": {
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Connection": "close",
"Cookie": "_gauges_unique_day=1; _gauges_unique_month=1; _gauges_unique_year=1; _gauges_unique=1",
"Host": "httpbin.org",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
},
"json": null,
"method": "GET",
"origin": "<ip-address-here>",
"url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
}
```

It seems like there was no POST to the URL. No errors seen in Excel. The form can be POSTed successfully to the same URL in a browser on the Mac. This issue is seen only in Excel 2016 for Mac. The same code works fine in Excel 2016 for Windows (7 and 10) and Excel online. Any insights to help resolve this is much appreciated.

See related question [Is the Excel add-in incompatible with Excel 2016 for Mac when using POST method for forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683237/is-the-excel-add-in-incompatible-with-excel-2016-for-mac-when-using-post-method)

Comment: We are investigating the issue and get back soon

Comment: We were informed by Tristan that a workaround is available. Will you be able to share that here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Excel 2016 on Mac to version 16.9.0 (18011602). We are able to POST from Excel 2016 for Mac! Thanks to the entire MS team.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683237/is-the-excel-add-in-incompatible-with-excel-2016-for-mac-when-using-post-method) for latest on this. Seems to be a duplicate issue.

Comment: We were informed by Tristan on Dec 14, 2017: folks are engaged with you on another thread, and have identified a product bug (and a potential workaround. Will you be able to provide us that workaround?

Comment: Sorry my reply to the other post hadn't made it till now. Could you please check there?