# Unable to POST <Form> from Excel 2016 for Mac or Excel for iPad

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

When testing an Excel Web Add-in that has an HTML form that `POSTs` to [httpbin Request & Response Service](https://httpbin.org/anything), the form is not being sent.

I am using Excel 2016 for Mac version is 15.39 (171010) running on High Sierra ver 10.13.1. I have seen the same issue with Excel for iPad.

Are Excel Add-ins incompatible with Excel 2016 for Mac and iPad when using `POST` method for forms?

There is a call to the site and page opens in a browser. However, there is no `POST`. This is what we see on the `httpbin.org` page – note the method `GET` and no parameters and their values seen:

```
{
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
    "method": "GET",
    "origin": "<ip-address-here>",
    "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
}
```

Using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#testForm").submit();
</script>

<form method="POST" id="testForm" action="https://httpbin.org/anything" accept-charset="UTF-8" target="_blank">
    <input type='hidden' name='mergeDataFormat' value='csv'>
    <input type="hidden" name="mergeData" id="mergeData" value='Name,Street,"City, State",ZIP Code'>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submitForm" />
</form>
```

Please refer to this post for more details: 
[Why doesn’t the form not POST in Excel 2016 for Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319517/why-doesn-t-the-form-not-post-in-excel-2016-for-mac)

The `AppDomain` was set to the following:

```
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://httpbin.org/</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

Tried with an `onsubmit` handler as shown below but I see no change.

```
<form method="POST" id="testForm" onsubmit="datasubmit()" action="https://httpbin.org/anything" accept-charset="UTF-8" target="_blank"></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function datasubmit() {
        console.log("Your details have submitted..........");
    }
</script>
```

The same code works fine when tested in a browser, outside of Excel 2016 for Mac. Also works fine in Excel Online. Only fails inside Excel 2016 for Mac.

Comment: It should be supported. Do you see the network trip when form is submitted? How are you calling post? Form action or do you call a on-submit handler (function)? You may want to try the latter and make the network call through your on-submit handler.

Comment: Updated the question with some details. Thanks!

Comment: Cool suggestion to try on-submit handler (function). We tried it - please see results in the lower part of the question. Get same issue. Any other ideas are appreciated. And thank you for the help.

Comment: We are investigating the issue and get back soon.

Comment: We were informed by Tristan that a workaround is available. Will you be able to share that here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is related to the usage of relative path in the [AppDomain](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/appdomain) segment of the add-in manifest. The relative paths such as `https://httpbin.org/anything` is not allowed and instead you'd need to just use the domain name `https://httpbin.org/`. Do you need to open the new window as part of the app or could you post the form to a different frame? In other words, could you explain the desired behavior of the form and post actions?

Comment: That change to the AppDomain was made and unfortunately did not change the outcome; updated this post.

Yes, we need to open a new window as part of the app since the next steps in using the data is done on a different site. The POST method is used to submit the data in the form. The site httpbin.org is used to just display the request and seems like POST is just not happening only for Excel for Mac. In other words, after testing this on multiple platforms & hosts, our concern is: why does the POST method fail only on Excel for Mac?

Comment: Based in the most recent information I have from eng. team, the POST issue on Mac will be addressed with this month's release. However, new window will be WebKit control browser and there may be differences in some behavior compared to full IE browser (shouldn't impact if all you are using is for HTML actions). It'd be great if you could share your add-in details (even sample for us to try) through the email contact you have to ensure that the fix will address your issues.

Comment: Glad to hear that! The project with info was sent to your email. Please confirm that you received the email and let us know if you need anything else. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't receive. Please email to suramam (at) microsoft email.

Comment: Sent email again to that address. Hope it arrives in one piece. Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Will you be able to provide info about this release such as the release date, how the release will be applied to Excel 2016 on Mac, etc? Thanks!

Comment: We updated Excel 2016 on Mac to version 16.9.0 (18011602) and everything works now. We are able to POST <Form> from Excel 2016 for Mac! Thanks to the entire MS team.