# HTTP POST not working on iOS 10.3.3

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

An HTTP POST is not sending the **body** to the server for iPad (IOS 10.3.3).

iPad (iOS 10.3.3), Outlook version 2.55.0 **DOES NOT work.**

iPad (iOS 11.X), Outlook version 2.55.0 **DOES work.**

iPhone (iOS 11.2.1), Outlook version 2.55.0 **DOES work**.

This may be related to post:

[Is the Excel add-in incompatible with Excel 2016 for Mac when using POST method for forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683237/is-the-excel-add-in-incompatible-with-excel-2016-for-mac-when-using-post-method)

To streamline test, I created a simple POST:

```
request.open('post', 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/XXX/', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.send('loginId=4&password=4');
```

I tried using application/json as well with no luck.

To eliminate some configuration error on my local server, I tried posting to zapier as well my local NodeJS restify server.  Again, iPhone (iOS 11.x) works, iPad (iOS 10.x) does not pass the body.

I compared the HTTP headers received from each post.  The only difference is:

iPad (iOS 10.3.3):

```
'content-length': '0',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
```

iPhone(iOS 11.2.1):

```
'content-length': '17',
'accept-encoding': 'br, gzip, deflate',
```

All other headers are the same.

<s>I'll be doing testing on an iPad iOS 11 soon to see if it's iIOS related</s> (updated in comments that I tested on iPad iOS 11 and it worked, so it's a 10.3 issue)

Comment: I just got access to an iPad with iOS 11 on it, and it works fine.  So it's probably iOS 10.X issues.

Comment: BTW, on certain iPad generation devices, you can't upgrade to iOS 11.

Comment: I just downloaded the IOS App version 2.60.0 that came out Jan 16th, and this issue persists.

Comment: Can you try removing content-type from request header and see if it works?

Comment: It does not.  I've also tried with application/json as the Content-Type with the appropriate JSON payload.

Comment: @NickCaruso this issue will be fixed by the next outlook update. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been trying to resolve a similar issue for a while. Will the new release this month solve your issue? Please see Sudhi Ramamurthy's response here
[Is the Excel add-in incompatible with Excel 2016 for Mac when using POST method for forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683237/is-the-excel-add-in-incompatible-with-excel-2016-for-mac-when-using-post-method)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not using the AppDomains as I'm not navigating anywhere from the add-in.  However, my REST API is not listed in the AppDomains.  Do you think that is the reason?  I have not had any issues with any other client, including Android.  Also, MSFT is failing the submission, in part because they can't login, because the HTTP post is failing

Comment: Product team is looking into this issue and should get back soon with an update.

Comment: @SudhiRamamurthy Do you know if your team solved this issue? I'm facing a similar issue with my own app, 10.3 not sending the POST data in a http request.