# What are the new testing criteria for the Excel add-in for Office 365?

Tags: office-js, office-store

Seems like new host and platform requirements have changed according to doc published on Dec. 1, 2017 here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability

We were told in a report from the MS Seller Dashboard to use add-in commands and make it compatible with Excel 2013, iOS Mac and the iPad.

However, according to the doc above by Microsoft, add-in commands are not listed for Excel 2013 and iOS.

The add-in availability Chart is gone 
https://dev.office.com/add-in-availablity

Therefore, what are the new testing criteria for the Excel add-in for Office 365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Excel add-ins submitted to the Office Store must be compatible with Excel 2016, Excel 2013, Excel for Mac and Excel Online, unless they are using APIs unsupported by one of these clients. See [Specify Office hosts and API requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements).

Your add-in is only required to support iPad, should you opt in during the submission process. See [Develop Office Add-ins for the iPad.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/develop-office-add-ins-for-the-ipad)

Since February 2017, all Excel add-ins must use add-in commands. In Office 2013, your add-in won't display add-in commands, and uses the value of SourceLocation to run your add-in as a single task pane add-in. See Step 2 of [Create add-in commands in your manifest for Excel, Word, and PowerPoint.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands)

Comment: Even though Excel add-ins are compatible with Excel 2016 for Mac, it fails in testing. Excel for Mac seems to be blocking the posting of a HTML form with POST method. See these on StackOverflow:

Why doesn't the form not POST in Excel 2016 for Mac?
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319517/why-doesn-t-the-form-not-post-in-excel-2016-for-mac)

Is the Excel add-in incompatible with Excel 2016 for Mac when using POST method for forms?
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683237/is-the-excel-add-in-incompatible-with-excel-2016-for-mac-when-using-post-method)

Comment: Hi Rick, I've highlighted your other two questions to the Office for Mac Teams for them to review and provide guidance as appropriate. Unfortunately the Office Store Validation Team can't help with this one!

Comment: Thanks! We are hoping the get some help from those teams soon.